# SharePoint 2013 search shows strange result count

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

OK, I just converted my 2010 solution to 2013. I use the search web parts for an article archive. I have configured it to only show content type of type "Artikkel" and to show 10 entries per page. When I load the page, it shows me the first 10 articles, but in the footer it says "About 109 results" and it only has page 1 and 2. When I navigate to page 2 it changes to "About 73 results" and page 3 appears. When I click page 3, it says "About 67 results" and page 4 appears.. and so on.... See images. This is in IE, in FireFox it is the same behavior but the numbers are different. Whats going on here?

[image: Settings]

[image: On page 1]

[image: On page 2]

[image: On page 3]

[image: On page 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. See here for more detail: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10638572-9240-44f5-a650-a0ff0782ee44/sharepoint-2010-search-result-count-inconsistent

In short, "On each post back, search API’s are called by OOB search results pagination controls and SharePoint returns different search counts for same query."

A possible solution is here:

http://spbreed.wordpress.com/2013/09/14/sharepoint-2013-solution-to-inconsistent-search-results-count/

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a custom post-security trimmer configured for your Search Service Application?

Comment: No, I don't have any post-security trimmer configured.